# Finding sequence until condition has been met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically I want to find a sequence in a dataframe until a specific condition has been met.

Supposed I have the following dataframe:

```
beginningTime | value | endingTime
10:00     | 1  | 10:01
10:01     | 2  | 10:02
10:02     | 1  | 10:03
10:03     | 2  | 10:04
10:04     | 2  | 10:05
10:05     | 3  | 10:06
10:06     | 4  | 10:07
10:07     | 5  | 10:08
10:08     | 4  | 10:09
10:09     | 3  | 10:10
10:10     | 2  | 10:11
10:11     | 1  | 10:12
10:12     | 2  | 10:13
10:13     | 3  | 10:14
10:14     | 4  | 10:15
10:15     | 5  | 10:16
...
```

In the dataframe above we've got the sequence 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 and the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I want both of these sequences, i.e. we're starting at 1 and ending at 5.

Shifting wouldn't work because I can't be sure if the sequence has always the same size. (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 would also be a valid sequence. Another valid sequence would be 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as long as the extracted sequence would start at the last 1 and not the first)

I've solved the problem using iterloops(), however as always there should be an easier approach than iterloops(), I know to only use it if there's no other possible solution available so I'd like to replace it.

**tl;dr:** How do I extract sequences starting at 1 and ending at 5 no matter what's inbetween and without knowing how far they're away from each other in the dataframe? Preferably getting the beginningTime of the sequence start and endingTime of the sequence end. This would only be a bonus though, I'm sure I'm able to figure this part out.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Your question is not very clear - at one point you mention - "Shifting wouldn't work because I can't be sure if the sequence has been consistently increased" and another point - "extract sequences starting at 1 and ending at 5 no matter what's inbetween"

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad, it does not have to be consistently increased, it just has to start at a 1 and end at a 5 I'll edit the question and can share the code later, currently on my phone. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

A naive solution is this. check it out

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,
     1,2,2,3,4,5,
     1,2,3,2,3,4,5,
     2,3,1,2,3]

temp_l = []
new_l = []
start = False
temp = 0

for i in l:
    
    if i == 1:
        start = True
    
    if i>=temp and start:
        temp_l.append(i)
    else:
        start = False
        
    temp = i
    
    if i == 5 and start:
        new_l.append(temp_l)
        temp_l = []
        start = False
        temp = 0
        
print(new_l)
#[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```